# Feel Jealous and Accomplished at the Same Time

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Looking for the word/idiom for the feeling/emotion where one feels jealous and accomplished at the same time.

For context, Person ABC (hereinafter, 'ABC') introduced and taught somebody (hereinafter, 'DEF') the basics of buying and selling stocks. Then after some time, ABC asked how are things going with the buying-and-selling, and found out that DEF earned a lot of money from the market. Now ABC feels both jealous and accomplished at the same time.

I don't think that this is **gloating** as it's just negative. Or perhaps a word (if there is) related to the feeling that masters have when their students surpass them? Imagining it as an equation, it's like:

> Jealousy + Feeling of Accomplishment = ???

Comment: Just a comment that "hereinafter" is very formal, and only ever used in legal documents.  In less formal documents, you might well write "John F Kennedy (JFK for short)" or indeed just use "JFK" on second reference.  (Many US politicans are recognised, at least during their time, by their initials: JFK, FDR, MLK and currently AOC.)  In your context, you might well write "Person A ... taught person B ..." and then later just call them "A" and "B".

Comment: By feeling of *accomplishment* do you mean feeling *pride in the other person*? I've never heard *accomplishment* used to mean anything other than feeling pride in *yourself*. In this question, whom or what is the object of the sense of accomplishment? (You for having taught them or them for having succeeded?)

Comment: @JasonBassford it seemed clear to me from "ABC feels both jealous and accomplished at the same time".

Comment: @WeatherVane So, what is the answer? Pride in yourself as the teacher or pride in the other as the student? (Feeling *accomplished* is awkward—normally, you either are or aren't accomplished at something. Feeling *accomplishment* is better. But it's still ambiguous.)

Comment: @JasonBassford the question does not mention pride but I agree with your earlier comment. It seemed clear to me that "ABC feels accomplished" would refer to ABC's satisfaction in having done a good job. I also agree that it's a poor choice of word, but that could also be said of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of no single word for this, and there's nothing wrong with simple description ("felt proud and a little jealous of DEF").

Here are some other phrases you might use:

- ABC felt a kind of **begrudging pride** at DEF's success.
- ABC was **proud** of DEF's success, and **somewhat envious** of her.
- ABC felt a **churlish pride** at DEF's success.
- ABC felt **pride** at having taught DEF so well, but it was a **green-eyed** pride.
- ABC was proud of having taught DEF how to trade, but did she have to be quite that good at it?

Definitions from OED.  "Green-eyed" is a pretty common phrase, "begrudge" not common, and "churlish" quite uncommon.

> **begrudge v.**   To grumble at, show dissatisfaction with; esp. to envy (one) the possession of; to give reluctantly, to be reluctant.
>
> **churlish adj.** Sordid, niggardly, stingy, grudging.
>
> **green-eyed adj.** Describing and alluding to jealousy.

Answer (score 2):

There have been similar questions on SE English Language & Usage such as

[Single word for happy and envious at the same time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122195/single-word-for-happy-and-envious-at-the-same-time)

[What's a word for a positive kind of “envy” without the sense of resentment?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266611/whats-a-word-for-a-positive-kind-of-envy-without-the-sense-of-resentment)

[A word that describes a positive form of envy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376838/a-word-that-describes-a-positive-form-of-envy)

but they don't satisfy this question, and **envy** and **jealousy** aren't quite the same thing. I don't know if the word you want even exists, although there are mixed-emotion words like *schadenfreude* (but which doesn't mean what you want). The closest emotion I can think of is **awe** which is given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/awe) as

> **awe**
>   NOUN
>
> **1A** feeling of reverential respect mixed with fear or wonder.
>   *How easy is it to lose yourself and what's important to you when you meet someone who impresses you, or someone who fills you with awe, or fear?*

That word doesn't really cover the ideas of **jealousy** and **satisfaction** but this is my example sentence.

> I was in **awe** of my former student DEF when he told me how much money he makes.